# Birthday with where clause

Tags: mysql, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Can any one help me with this

Script

This is what i want to achive

table

```
id  name    tag_id  status      dob
== ======= ======== ========   ======== 
1   a       1        Married    02/23/1977
2   b       1        Single     02/23/1978
3   c       2        Single     02/23/1960
4   d       1        Married    02/23/1985
5   e       2        Married    02/23/1999
6   f       2        Diovice    02/23/1999
7   g       1        Married    02/28/1999
8   h       2        Married    02/28/1999
9   i       1        Married    03/12/1990
```

I will love to get the present/ current birthday celebrant with mysql query
here is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=MONTH(CURDATE())
    AND (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=DAY(CURDATE())))
    OR (DAY(LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')))=29
    AND (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(bob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=29)
    AND (DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))=28))
    AND ( STATUS = 'Married' OR STATUS = 'Single' )
    AND tag_id = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

my problem is the above code is just returing all present bithday but what i want is like this:

result:

```
1   a       1        Married    02/23/1977
2   b       1        Single     02/23/1978
4   d       1        Married    02/23/1985
7   g       1        Married    02/28/1999
```

Wrong result (produce by the above query):

```
1   a       1        Married    02/23/1977
2   b       1        Single     02/23/1978
4   d       1        Married    02/23/1985
7   g       1        Married    02/28/1999
8   h       2        Married    02/28/1999
```

And what i want, i only want Birthday Celebrant for today that/ where is ID = 1. Like i specify with the first result.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more your question

Comment: the `OR` query is giving you the wrong result. why did you take that exactly?

Comment: I think what you desire lies within this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=DAY(CURDATE())))` 

I'm not very sure about the part after 'OR'

Comment: non of the answer still not working, the or statement is specify and to include the LEAP YEAR Birthday celebrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This later worked out for me, it might help others and i will love to see more improvement of this answer:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')) = DAY(NOW()) AND TAG_ID = 2 AND STATUS IN ('single','married')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(dob) = DAY(GETDATE())
and tag_id = 1 and status in ('pending','active')
```

This should work.

Comment: I think this is what he wants. The first part of his query before the 'OR' alone is good to give his desired result. I'm not sure why he goes with the part after the 'OR' statement.

Comment: I am phpmyadmin for mysql so GETDATE() function cannot not be found in PhpMyAdmin and when i change it GETDATE() to NOW() is returning empty result

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: Are you sure that there's someone celebrating their birthday during the time that you ran your script @MichaelCodes

Comment: Year i am 100% sure, if  there is no birthday celerant i can easy change any users date to current to test my script @BennjoeMordeno

Comment: Here is my own method that works for me, please kind affect the changes to this to accept your answer:

Comment: SELECT
 * 
FROM 
table 
WHERE 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW()) 
AND 
DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')) = DAY(NOW()) 
AND 
TAG_ID = 2 
AND 
STATUS IN ('single','married')

Comment: `SELECT
 * 
FROM 
table 
WHERE 
MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW()) 
AND 
DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')) = DAY(NOW()) 
AND 
TAG_ID = 2 
AND 
STATUS IN ('single','married')`

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno

Comment: @MichaelCodes you can answer your own question. Just submit an answer and mark it ad the correct answer. Good for you that you got a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` query is giving you the wrong result.(I am not sure why you have taken)

This is making an **or condition for first two queries and remaining ones**

So, enclose the `OR` queries within brackets.

Then, you will get your `AND  tag_id = 1` executed.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    (MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND
    (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=DAY(CURDATE())))

 OR 

 (
    (DAY(LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')))=29 
  AND 
    (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(bob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=29)
  AND
    (DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))=28))
  )

AND
    ( STATUS = 'ACTIVE' OR STATUS = 'PENDING' )
AND
    tag_id = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: @Michael Codes, please check my answer.

Comment: I test the code is still not working is still returning both birtday for id 1 and 2, and i only want birthday for with by ID inclusive with LEAP YEAR

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: `OR (DAY(LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')))=29
AND (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(bob, '%d/%m/%Y'))=29)
AND (DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))=28))`, what are these for?

Comment: 29 and 28 is to check for leap year month that end with 28 and 29 like febuary